# getUserMedia in Microsoft Edge captures maximum of 2M pixel

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to use the new "Media Capture and Streams API", I ran the example from here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Demos/tree/master/photocapture

I'm trying to set better resolution but all I get is only 1920*1080 pixels.
For instance, I tried the following code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
                width: 2560,
                height: 1440,
                deviceId: { exact: webcamList[currentCam] }
            }
        }).then(initializeVideoStream).catch(getUserMediaError);
```

Can it do better than 2M pixel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An expert guy from this field told me that the real problem here is the video resolution (which is pretty low nowadays), Bad image capturing resolution stems from that...

Every browser (also Chrome and FF) will capture an image with pretty bad resolution (1M pixel or 2M pixel top).

Answer (score 0):

it is not a Microsoft edge issue, this is more of a GPU and hardware spec affecting the video resolution and ultimately the image capturing.

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in a better video camera, you can. `getUserMedia()` which the demo uses, gives you video, not just a picture, and 1920*1080 pixels is HD, e.g. pretty good for video.